# Strikethrough UITableViewCell text field after cell is "complete"

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

How can I strikethrough text in a UITableViewCell during and after a UIContextualAction? (If it can't be done during, after only would be helpful)

[Strikethrough example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GMtC.png)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
    let doneAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "DONE", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Done left")

        self.dailyTasks.append("\(self.dailyTasks[indexPath.row])")
        self.dailyTasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.dailyTasks, forKey: "dailyTasks")

        self.dailyTable.reloadData()

        success(true)

    })
    doneAction.backgroundColor = .darkGray

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [doneAction])

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should display label text as attributedtext. Try this code. The getRespectiveCell method is not implemented. Put your own logic to get respective cell for that indexpath

```swift
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your Text")
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

let cell = getRespectiveCell(indexPath.row)
cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributeString
```

Comment: Thank @ahmed. I was able to get the respective cell with the following:

let cell = self.dailyTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)